# Download QGIS 2.18 nightly

Tags: qgis

Does any one know where can I download the 2.18 nightly version of qgis? 
and would you give me some information about it?

Comment: What is your OS? Are you looking for the 2.99 version?

Comment: For 2.99 Standalone installers, see https://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/?C=M;O=D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few versions you might want, I am assuming Windows since you did not specify. All of which can be installed through the [OSGeo4W Installer](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/), using the "Advanced Install option":

[image]

From here, if you want the nightly builds of the 2.18 dev, it would be:

> qgis-rel-dev currently version 2.18.15-1

For the long term release nightly builds it would be:

> qgis-ltr-dev currently version 2.14.21-1

And for QGIS 3 nightly builds it would be:

> qgis-dev currently version 2.99.0-236